# how to count rows in a data frame in python?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 

year=np.array([1851.203,1851.632,1851.969,1851.975,1852.314,1852.347,1852.358,1852.385,1852.977,1853.196,1853.229,1853.319,1853.5,1854.135,1856.396,1856.506,1856.539,1856.618,1857.138,1857.404])
coal=pd.DataFrame(year)

def disaster(year1,year2):
    disaster = (coal >= year1) & (coal <= year2)
    print year.sum()

disaster(1852,1856)
>>>360806.155
```

i want to write a function which will give me number of years in between two years. like when i put years 1852,1856 it add all the years but i want how many rows (integer) are in between that interval.

For example, 1851 is four times and 1852 is 5 times, when i put the interval (1851,1852) it will sum up and give out put as 9. i want this for any two years.

Any one can help please ?

Comment: Use `range(year1, year2)` to get everything in between. Also combine it with length to know how many years you have. Don;t forget the inclusive and exclusive elements in the range.

Comment: i am sorry. i don't get it. where to put range ?

Comment: Sorry are you asking for the number of rows or the number of years? for instance in your example there would be 10 rows but there are 3 years between 1852 and 1856

Comment: @ EdChum- yes, number of rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def disaster(year1,year2):
    return  np.sum((coal >= year1) & (coal <= year2+1))

print disaster(1851,1852)

>>> 
0    9
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

I've modified your code based on some assumptions. I think what you are trying to do is use your mask to mask into the original df, print or get the sum, and additionally get the length. To get the length you need to use the mask with the original df, call `dropna()` to drop the `NaN` rows, and then call `len` on the resultant df:

```
In [16]:

year=np.array([1851.203,1851.632,1851.969,1851.975,1852.314,1852.347,1852.358,1852.385,1852.977,1853.196,1853.229,1853.319,1853.5,1854.135,1856.396,1856.506,1856.539,1856.618,1857.138,1857.404])
coal=pd.DataFrame(year)

def disaster(year1,year2):
    total = (coal >= year1) & (coal <= year2)
    print (coal[total].sum())
    print(len(coal[total].dropna()))

disaster(1852,1856)
0    18529.76
dtype: float64
10
```

Comment: @ EdChum- I have modified my question. i want to see the number of rows in between two years.FOr example, 1851 is four times and 1852 is 5 times, when i put the interval (1851,1852) it will sum up and give out put as 9. i want this for any two years.Thanks

Comment: @AlfradNobel your conditions do not reflect this, you have exactly 4 rows between 1851 and 1852, the additional rows you refer to are larger than 1852 and less than 1853, you could just add 1 to year2 so : `total = (coal >= year1) & (coal <= year2 + 1)`

Comment: @EdChum-  in your code the first print gives  ( 0  18529.76), why this 0 is for ? why not only 18529.76 ?

Comment: @AlfradNobel it's printing the series value, `0` is the index, if you wanted just the value then do `print(coal[total].sum()[0])` this accesses the first row of the series (there is only one)